# Can child classes inherit instance variables from their parent class in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, do instance variables need to be manually defined in a child class, or can they be inherited directly from the parent class?

E.g.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation, subject):
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation
        self.subject = subject
```

Instead of redeclaring the name and occupation instance variables in the child class, can these be inherited another way?

Comment: Normally you would call the superclass init, by using `super()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `__init__` from the parent class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, occupation, subject):
        Person.__init__(self, name, occupation)
        self.subject = subject
```